# select a specific div in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add a class on a specific div.

My code actually looks like:

```
$("div")[0].addClass("test");
```

Here's the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b9f7vog0/1/) where my problem occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery collections are objects with length, often referred to as "array-like".
They contain the native DOM nodes, and different jQuery "stuff".
Because the collection have length, the underlying DOM nodes can be accessed with bracket notation, but that gives you the native DOM node, not a jQuery object, and native DOM nodes don't have an `addClass` method, jQuery objects do.

You should be using [`eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) to get a new jQuery collection containing only the first element.
The number passed is the index of the element you want to get, it's zero-based, so `0` is the first element.

```
$("div").eq(0).addClass("test");
```

Answer (score 0):

Update from

```
$("div")[0].addClass("test");
```

to

```
$($("div")[0]).addClass("test");
```

Working version - https://jsfiddle.net/b9f7vog0/2/

Answer (score 0):

`addClass` needs to be called on a jQuery-Object, so you need to make sure, that `$("div")[0]` is converted to that, so put it in `$()`:

```
$($("div")[0]).addClass("test");
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You may try `first` method instead of `[0]`, which will return a jQuery object on which you can call `addClass` method.

```
$("div").first().addClass("test");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [jQuery's eq-selector](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) to select an nth item. EG:

```js
$("div").eq(0).addClass("test");
```

```css
div{
  height:30px;
  width: 30px;
  border:1px black solid;
  display:inline-block;
}
section{
  font-size:0;
}
.test{
  background-color: brown;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:

```
$("div").first().addClass("test"); //return a jQuery object

$("div").eq(0).addClass("test"); //zero-based index

$("div").filter(function(index, el) {
  return index === 0;
}).addClass("test");
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `$('div')[0]` is not an jQuery object.
I have long forgotten jQuery but try this:

`$($("div")[0]).addClass("test"); // Works`